# how to set socket server port in react app in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I have deployed my react app to Heroku and also the socket server. Heroku assigns a different port every time than how I can set it in react app.

ex. for localhost: im setting socket server post 8900 and in react app, im using - `socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8900");`

Comment: Have you tried setting the PORT via env?

Comment: the problem is how I can know the port number assigned to my socket server. I can log but I'm searching that can I add a log when server starts

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Heroku's free tier. And if the server is idle for 30 mins then it will be automatically going offline. When it gets a new req, it starts again but with a different port assigned by Heroku. So, I guess in the free tier, we can't host a socket server in Heroku's free tier as its port will be changed every time it restarts.